# open mht file in phone:WebBrowser

Tags: webbrowser-control, windows-phone-7.1, mhtml

I have an application which displays help to user using webbrowser control. Now i'm able to display HTML correctly but If i try to display mht file (which contains images). It throws System.NullReferenceException. Both files are located at same location.

Lot of folks are deploying mht file to isolatedstorage and then reading it from there. Is there easy way todo this?